# How to update person or group field from SharePoint 2013 workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, person

I am stuck on very basic requirement. I have a person or group field on SharePoint Online list which I want to update from a SharePoint Designer workflow. When I assign the value "User who created current item" to this person/group field. However, it is not updating and giving me this error.

> "The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more
>   columns for the item require a different type of information."

Comment: Are you returning the value as a string? (As opposed to a display name or email address)

Answer (score 1):

My bet would be that the person or group field that you want to update allows for multiple selections. A properly formatted string for a single user in a multiple user lookup field is `00;#Name, Display`. As such I would recommend creating a local variable, for example "created_user" and have the first step of the workflow be Set that variable to `[%Current Item:Created By%];#[%Current Item: Created By%]` where the first `[%Current Item: Created By%]` returns `User ID Number`, and the second one returns `Display Name`. Then when you do the update list item action when you get to the Value assignment screen, in the `"To this value:"` section use the `fx` button and NOT the `"..."` button. The `Data Source` will then be `"Workflow variables and Parameters"`, the `"Field from source:` will be the variable that you created, the `"Return Field as:"` will be `String`