# Setting person column with workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, column, person, workflow-tasks-list

I am using a reusable workflow to collect feedback on a document. One of the initiation form parameters is "owner" with the "person or group" information type. I am trying to get the "owner" parameter to populate in the workflow task column. When starting the workflow the column returns with an empty field.

So far I have tried:

- Created a variable "owner_retainer"
- Set owner_retainer to -1;#[%Parameter: Owner%] (as string)
- Update task field

And:

- set task field to value | set owner to Parameter:owner

Along with various other combinations.

I have tried reviewing other answers found [here](https://www.hornerit.com/2009/07/setting-person-or-group-column-in.html) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156133/how-to-update-person-or-group-field-from-sharepoint-2013-workflow) but am unable to deploy them on my workflow. May I get some assistance with this. Feel free to send me links/resources where this questions has been answered before.

Comment: add log to history list at the starting of the workflow and see if you are getting value in owner parameter correctly or not.

Comment: I added Log Parameter:Owner in Before a Task is Assigned (change behavior of single task). In the workflow history I see my name in the description column. Should this be appended with something?